# LXD container restricted to specific user

Tags: security, lxc, lxd

If I have 2 users with the 'lxd' group, user-1 and user-2. If user-1 starts a container, then I think that user-2 may stop it, destroy it or even run command on that container or connect via ssh to it.

Is there a way to allow users to use `lxc` utility without letting them having entiere control on the lxd instances ?

What I would like to achieve is letting some users the right to create containers, which would have a shared folder in their home. And ensure that some user cannot access to another user's container.

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible.

LXD does support some [Role Based Access Control](https://lxd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security/#role-based-access-control-rbac), but the roles only allow some operations to be restricted for certain users and not a full separation between users.